# How to get the path of the exexuter in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, path

I am using Visual studio 2008 and I want to get the absolute path of the .exe file?
meaning when the user opens the exe file, I need to know its absolute path??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Windows try the following:

```
char ExeName[8192]; // or what ever max. size you expect.

if (0 != GetModuleFileName (NULL, ExeName, sizeof (ExeName)))
{
  printf ("Your array was probably not large enough. Call GetLastError for details\n");
}
```

If you compile for unicode use wchar_t.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `_pgmptr` or `_wpgmptr` global variable is probably the easiest way.* (They're in `stdlib.h`.)

*Note: Under some rather rare circumstances, it's possible that this won't work... in that case, use `GetModuleFileName(NULL, ...)`;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain a path of the current process, you should use API function:

```
GetModuleFileName
```

But, if you want to obtain a full path of the process that is not written by you, use

```
GetModuleFileNameEx
```

Above function expects one argument more than GetModuleFileName - it is a HANDLE of a process which path is supposed to be obtained. It is explained in more details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).